# Palindrome in base 4

Tags: prolog, palindrome

This code should check if a given number is palindrome in base 4.

If given number is palindrome, solution is **true**, but if not, then that is error.

```
baza_4(0,[]).

baza_4(N,[R|Xs]) :-
   N1 is floor(N/4),
   baza_4(N1,Xs),
   R is mod(N,4).

splitR(N,Xs) :-
   baza_4(N,Ys),
   reverse(Xs,Ys).

pal(N) :- 
   baza_4(N,Xs),
   reverse(Xs,Xs).
```

Comment: ...and the problem is that it doesn't terminate?

Comment: Yes, nothing happens.

Comment: You should guard against entering on the second clause of` baza_4` if N=0, i.e.  `N > 0`. Also as these seem to be integers, use integer division `N // 4` instead of `floor(N/4)`

Comment: Now it works, but I don't know why. Why  must  I write N>0?